# Node.JS + Mongoose callback hell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

how can i save mongoose to db but wait other collection to load first?
The platform and genres is empty, because the "save" function run before platform and genres loaded, please help!

```
var platforms = []; //load platforms
body.release_dates.forEach(function(elem){
    Platform.findOne({ id : elem.platform}, function(err, result) {
            platforms.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id));
        });
});

var genres = []; //load genre
body.genres.forEach(function(elem){
    Genre.findOne({id: elem}, function(err, result){
        genres.push(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id));
    })
});



//prepare to save!
var game = {
    igdb_id : body.id,
    name : body.name,
    summary : body.summary,
    storyline : body.description,
    genres : genres,
    platforms : platforms, // <- genres amd platforms empty and not wait platforms and genre array to complete
    release_date : body.original_release_date,
    cover : body.cover.cloudinary_id,
    videos: body.videos
};

var data = new Game(game);
data.save(function(err, game){
    if(err){
        res.send("500");
        return console.error(err);
    }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of a decent use case for promises (which are an excellent tool enabling you to perform async operations with ease) and should help you in future.

The issue with the current code is that the `findOne` operations are async and would complete after some time. In the meantime, the next lines will start executing. Thus, when you reach at the `save` state, none of the `findOne` would have completed and you get empty arrays

Two popular nodejs libraries which implement promises are [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com). Latest versions of NodeJS also implement the default [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

The following is the code using Bluebird. You essentially have to create promises for each of your database operation involving `findOne` in Platform and Genre. When all of these complete, you have to start executing the final `save` part. This is achieved using the [Promise.all](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) functionality which would wait till all the promises are completed.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

var platformPromises = []; //load platforms
body.release_dates.forEach(function(elem){
    platformPromises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Platform.findOne({ id : elem.platform}, function(err, result) {
            if(err) 
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id));
        });
    }))

});

var genrePromises = []; //load genre
body.genres.forEach(function(elem){
    genrePromises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Genre.findOne({id: elem}, function(err, result){
            if(err) 
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id));
        });
    }))

});

var allPromises = platformPromises.concat(genrePromises);

Promise.all(allPromises).then(function (result) {
    //prepare to save!

    var platforms = [];
    var genres = [];

    for(var i=0; i<platformPromises.length; i++)
        platforms.push(result[i]); // result come out in same order as the promises

    for(var i=platformPromises.length; i<result.length; i++)
        genres.push(result[i]);

    var game = {
        igdb_id : body.id,
        name : body.name,
        summary : body.summary,
        storyline : body.description,
        genres : genres,
        platforms : platforms,
        release_date : body.original_release_date,
        cover : body.cover.cloudinary_id,
        videos: body.videos
    };

    var data = new Game(game);
    data.save(function(err, game){
        if(err){
            res.send("500");
            return console.error(err);
        }

    });

})
```

Comment: Mongoose already returns promises if you leave off the callback function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just wanted to explain how to use promises, for someone coming from a synchronous background.

Comment: @hyades, nice, but what if you have three array to get, you just mix platformPromises and genrePromises in "result", what the "for" function look like if there are three array?

example, platformPromises,genrePromises,themePromises

Comment: @tonywei yea the result array will be same order as the input array,

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first off, mongoose (at least any recent version) already supports promises if you leave off the callback... second, the example below uses promises combined with async fuctions.  This is behind an options flag in Node 7+, so you should be using babel to transpile otherwise.

I put comments where you should optimize your mongodb calls, but left the logic as close to above as possible, hopefully this helps you.

The key take aways are...

- Use Promises, and don't be afraid to create additional functions to break up logic
- Promise.all can be used to wait for parallel actions to complete
- `async` functions are awesome.

*CODE:*

```
// will asynchronously map your release date elements to the Platform
async function getPlatforms(releaseDates) {
  // TODO: change to single query with only needed properties
  return await Promise.all(releaseDates.map(
    elem => Platform.findOne({ id: elem.platform })
  ));
}

// will asynchronously map your genre list into the appropriate ObjectId objects
async function getGenres(genres) {
  // TODO: change to return only single properties in a single query
  var genres = await Promise.all(genres.map(elem => Genre.findOne({ id: elem })));
  return genres.map(result => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id));
}

// asynchronous request handler (ALWAYS use a try/catch for this with express)
// not sure if current/future versions will allow for promise resulting 
// handlers/errors
async function saveGameDetails(req,res) {
  try {
    // array destructured assignment, decomposes the array
    // await will await the promise, and promise.all will take an array
    // and wrap them into a single promise.
    var [platforms, genres] = await Promise.all([
      getPlatforms(body.release_dates),
      getGenres(body.genres)
    ]);

    //prepare to save!
    var game = {
        igdb_id : body.id,
        name : body.name,
        summary : body.summary,
        storyline : body.description,
        genres : genres,
        platforms : platforms, // <- genres amd platforms empty and not wait platforms and genre array to complete
        release_date : body.original_release_date,
        cover : body.cover.cloudinary_id,
        videos: body.videos
    };

    var data = new Game(game);
    await data.save(); //already a promise, just wait for it

    // return normal result
    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
  } catch(err) {
    // generic error handler, may want to have this even more generic via express
    res.status(500).json({
      error: {
        message: err.message || 'Unknown Server Error';
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can use to do this work is async module, which is perfect to do that kind of tasks. Intall using npm: `npm i -S async`

```
    var async = require ('async');

        var platforms = [];
        var genres = [];

        async.parallel([
        function(cb){
            body.release_dates.forEach(function(elem){
                Platform.findOne({ id : elem.platform}, function(err, result){
                    cb(null,mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id))
                });
            });
         },
        function(cb){
            body.genres.forEach(function(elem){
                Genre.findOne({id: elem},enter code here function(err, result){
                    cb(null,mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result._id));
                })
            });
         }],function(err,results){
            //here you'll get an array of results ordered by your tasks
                if(!err){
                    platforms.push(results[0])
                    genres.push(results[1])
                }
             })
```

I didn't run this code, but that's the way, if you need more information you can read the docs: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html